# Using "or" in list comprehensions

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I feel like I've somehow misunderstood the fundamental concept of how the 'or' keyword works in Python.

I have the following code:

```
word = "aarrgh"

print(*[x for x in word if x == "a" or "r"])
```

and this is giving me:

```
a a r r g h
```

The same thing happens when using `==` or `!=`.

What am I missing here? I cant find anything online explaining this so sorry if this is something obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem isn't specifically related to the comprehension.  It's a question of how `or` and `==` works.  `x == "a" or "r"` means `(x == "a") or "r"`.  You should use one of these instead.

```
print(*[x for x in word if x in ["a", "r"]])
print(*[x for x in word if x == "a" or x == "r"])
```

Comment: not to mention "r" will always count as true...